# EXC_BAD_ACCESS - How is this code causing a leak? Traced via malloc_history & NSZombieEnabled

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, ios4, uiviewcontroller

**UPDATE** (at bottom): *Added entire viewWillAppear: method implementation to show how the three UIViewControllers are allocated / deallocated into the UIScrollView.*

I have a root ViewController which contains a `UIScrollView`. This `UIScrollView` itself contains 3 different `UIViewController`s (setup as `NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate`s for separate `UITableView`s.)

I need to **reload** the root ViewController's `UIScrollView` at one point when we come back to the view so I do this at the beginning of:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [dataViewScroller.subviews 
                 makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
 .......
 // and we proceed to re-load the 3 UIViewControllers into the UIScrollView.
 // From testing this all seems to work fine.
 // The **problem** is that that as soon as this method ends - I get an
 // EXC_BAD_ACCESS error described above.
 // If the above line is removed, everythign works fine.
}
```

Here is the viewDidLoad method for the each of the `UIViewControllers` loaded into the `UIScrollView` is as follows:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.expensesTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

self.theTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
self.theTableView.rowHeight = 44;

UIView *containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44)] autorelease];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

// Setting up and aligning the label in the center of our view.
UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)];   
headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(self.headerText, @"");
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
headerLabel.center = containerView.center;
headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

[containerView addSubview:headerLabel];

// HOW IS THIS A LEAK? CAUSES EXC_BAD_ACCESS If Not commented out
//NSLog(@"Test - %@", headerLabel);
//[headerLabel release];

[self.view addSubview:containerView];

NSError *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);  // Fail
}
```

}

The code above has the line `headerLabel release]` commented out. With this out the program runs fine! If I enable the line `[headerLabel release]`, which I technically **SHOULD** have enabled since otherwise it's a LEAK, GDB then reports the following:

```
 MyAppTest[11110:207] *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d66b60
(gdb)

This is the output from malloc_history trace using the above memory address:

Identifier:      MyAppTest
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  gdb-i386-apple-darwin [10116]

Date/Time:       2011-03-15 03:14:47.855 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

ALLOC 0x5996770-0x599678f [size=32]: thread_a037a540 |start | main | UIApplicationMain | -[UIApplication _run] | CFRunLoopRunInMode | CFRunLoopRunSpecific | __CFRunLoopRun | __CFRunLoopDoSource1 | __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ | PurpleEventCallback | _UIApplicationHandleEvent | -[UIApplication sendEvent:] | -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] | -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] | -[UIApplication _reportAppLaunchFinished] | CA::Transaction::commit() | CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) | CALayerLayoutIfNeeded | -[CALayer layoutSublayers] | -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] | -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] | -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] | -[AccountViewController viewWillAppear:] | -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] | -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] | -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] | -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] | -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] | -[NSSQLCore _newRowsForFetchPlan:selectedBy:withArgument:] | -[NSSQLCore _prepareResultsFromResultSet:usingFetchPlan:withMatchingRows:] | CFStringCreateWithCString | __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 | _CFRuntimeCreateInstance | malloc_zone_malloc
```

Pulling my hair out because there is absolutely ZERO messages or calls made to `headerLabel` after I **release** it. Anyone have any suggestions? please??

**---- UPDATE**

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[dataViewScroller.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

[self.myTableViewControllers removeAllObjects];
self.myTableViewControllers = nil;

// All database modifcations should dynamically reload when the view reappears

/* RE-OBTAIN CATEGORIES */
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [myAppTestAppDelegate managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyObjectType" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSError *errorInRequest = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errorInRequest];

if(errorInRequest)
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", errorInRequest, [errorInRequest userInfo]);
    abort();
}

[fetchRequest release];

kNumberOfPages = [results count];

dataViewPageControl.numberOfPages = kNumberOfPages;
    dataViewPageControl.currentPage = 0;
dataViewScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(dataViewScroller.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, dataViewScroller.frame.size.height);

// the view controllers are created lazily
// in the meantime, load the array with placeholders which will be replaced on demand
NSMutableArray *controllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < kNumberOfPages; i++) {
    [controllers addObject:[NSNull null]];
}

self.myTableViewControllers = controllers;
[controllers release];

int index = 0;

for (NSManagedObject *type in results) {
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:index withIdentifier:[type valueForKey:@"name"]];
    index++;
}

}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page withIdentifier:(NSString *)ident {

if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= kNumberOfPages) return;

MyTableListViewController *controller = [myTableViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];

if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null]) {
    controller = [[MyTableListViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page withHeader:ident];
    controller.managedObjectContext = [myAppTestAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
    [myTableViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    [controller release];
}
if (nil == controller.view.superview) {
    CGRect frame = dataViewScroller.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [dataViewScroller addSubview:controller.view];
}
}
```

So as you can see, they are always loaded dynamically when the Root ViewController loads. This is because the user can go to an *Account Settings* type admin page and add additional categories to their setup. When returning to the Root View the NEW / OR DELETED categories must be rendered in the scroll view. If they had 3 Cateogories (ie. 3 TableViewControllers) initially and went to the admin page and created a new one, when returning the the UIScrollView should reload with all 4 categories (4 dynamically created TableViewControllers.) Does this make sense?

Comment: Why not instantiate all view controllers once and only shuffle their views around? Would be so much easier. Instantiating a VC but not adding its view to a parent is no problem at all.

Comment: Personally, I would re-create the views only when the admin settings have been changed. It seems like overkill to change them every time the view loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @e.James and @mvds for helping trace this down. Based off the *malloc history* in this post and @e.James initial suggestion to investigate the fetch I managed to drill down deeper and find the culprit issue.

It was the following code which gets called to create and alloc on of the UIViewControllers found in the UIScrollView:

```
// Load the view nib and initialize the pageNumber ivar.
- (id)initWithPageNumber:(int)page withHeader:(NSString *)header withType:(NSManagedObject *)type {
if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"ExpenseListViewController" bundle:nil]) {

    pageNumber = page;
            // below WAS the offending line.
    // headerText = header;
            self.headerText = header;

}
return self;
```

}

Now it it's correct and everything works as intended. Basically I was not using the *setter* method on a retained & synthesized property (*headerText=header*). Adding the **self.** fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your view controller is not prematurely released?

It looks like the `headerLabel` is (over)released, but that doesn't originate from your code, since it is retained by `containerView`, which is retained by `self.view`, which is retained by your view controller.

So try to modify your view controllers `dealloc` method as such:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
     NSLog(@"View controller deallocing");
     // ... whatever you had here
     [super dealloc];
}
```

and check the console for the log message.

Comment: @mvds I've done this already and I do have a message inside the dealloc for the ViewControllers that get loaded into the ScrollView. They do get released and I see the message as a result of the first line in my viewWillAppear method inside the root view controller. "[dataViewScroller.subview makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];"

Comment: Ah, that is a big hint to what is going on. If your view *controllers* are being deallocated when their views are released, that means that you are not retaining the controllers themselves. Generally speaking, a viewController owns its view, and some other object owns the viewController. How are you (re)creating the controllers in your root viewController viewWillAppear method?

Comment: Really? The view controller is released when you release a subview? Then you should definitely check if you retain the view controller yourself. Could you share the code instantiating/initializing/releasing the view controller?

Comment: @mvds: it *can* be, if you haven't retained it anywhere. It sounds to me like Straddle is adding the subviews but not retaining the controllers themselves.

Comment: I agree that we should probably see the code in the root `viewWillAppear:` method

Comment: @e.James: sorry for the confusion, we have posted the same observation and are in full agreement, I responded to Straddles remark - not yours. You don't seem to get a "reload comments" popup on SO when some else comments while you are typing a comment...

Answer (score 1):

**Update** (based on comments):

Cocoa does a lot of view magic behind the scenes, so I think I can see where the problem is. The `viewWillAppear` notification is automatically sent to all view controllers that are about to appear. This means that it will be sent to your root controller, *and all three of the viewcontrollers whose views you have just released!*. To put it simply, you are deleting parts of a view heirarchy while Cocoa is in the process of sending messages to the views within that heirarchy.

To solve the problem, I would recommend something a little less drastic. You should not need to completely destroy and re-create the three subviews every time your view will appear. Your root viewController should keep a reference to the three viewControllers that it creates, and then simply send them a message to refresh or redisplay their content when the time comes.

Comment: @e.James I've tried commenting out the entire 'if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]' block but it still seems to crash on that '[headerLabel release]' line as long as I have it :( I think @mvds might be on to something down below but I'm not certain how to locate it.

Comment: @e.James wow! I suspect you hit the nail in the coffin. I wasn't aware that viewWillDisappear will also notify all subview view controllers as well. This must be *EXACTLY* what the issue is then. Although, shouldn't the problem be fixable by calling '[super viewWillAppear:animated]' first before anything else in the viewWillAppear method? _Then I could release all three of the view controllers_ **after** _super has been called?_ Although I've tried this and it didn't work :( Will update the original post with the entire viewWillAppear method.

Comment: @Straddle, It looks like Cocoa's code will wait for the first call to `viewWillAppear` to return before it makes the call for the subviews. It also appears to ignore any changes made to those subviews in the meantime.

Comment: @e.James I've added code above. The viewWillAppear and the helper method _loadScrollViewWithPage_. Based on the fact that it appears Cocoa's will wait for the viewWillAppear call to return, perhaps this is not the method that I should be wiping subviews and re-allocating the TableViewControllers ? Hmmm.

Comment: Starting to wonder if I should maybe move most of this configuration to an _AnimationDidStop_ @selector method instead of the viewWillAppear method. That will avoid Cocoa sending msgs to the dealloc'd viewcontrollers.

Comment: @e.James ARGH! Same thing with _viewDidAppear_. Tried moving an UIActivityIndicatorView into the _viewDidAppear_ method and then doing the deallocs and lazy loading - but it appears Cocoa still tries to reference the old dealloc'd viewcontrollers after _viewDidAppear_ completes. Any suggestions where to move this?

Comment: @Straddle: Honestly, I would find a way to move it out of the view heirarchy altogether. If the arrangement is only changed when your admin settings are changed, then *that* moment would be the best time to do any view rearranging. You could add a method to your root viewController called `-reloadPages`, and simply call that whenever the settings have been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually releasing containerView after adding it to self.view, rather than using autorelease?

Answer (score 0):

if this happens once the method ends then it would suggest that the program is trying to access local data that gets deleted once the method exits.